# Chrome save history only for 7 days

Tags: google-chrome, history

is there a way how to set Chrome to save history and cache only for last 7 days? Rest of the history will be removed automatically after this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome does not support this feature, although some plugins do. You can try [Click & Clean](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickclean/ghgabhipcejejjmhhchfonmamedcbeod?hl=en).

Comment: Note that Click & Clean only achieves the *opposite*: it deletes all data *from* the last X days, not *before* the last X days.