# Chrome: automatically only keep history from the last X days

Tags: google-chrome, privacy

I'm looking for a Chrome extension (or other method for Chrome) for ensuring that only the most recent X days of history and browsing data are stored. All the extensions I can find seem to be geared up for deleting either *everything ever* or the *previous* X days of history (e.g. remove everything from the past week).

To some extent, I find it helpful to retain history for the last week or so (for autocompletion and so on), but I see no need for Chrome to remember my browsing history since the dawn of time. I'm not looking for tools to 'clear my tracks' of recent activity (which seems to be the purpose of most 'history cleaning' tools, and what the answer to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/889818/chrome-save-history-only-for-7-days) suggests), but rather something automatic that just clears things out once they reach a certain period of time. If I haven't visited a site in the last week or so, I probably don't need to keep it in my history for quick access. Ideally, I'm looking for something which achieves this automatically, rather than having to remember to click a button regularly.

I realise that my question straddles somewhere between 'usability' and 'privacy'. On the one hand, I care about privacy out of principle, but on the other, I care about usability - I find it hard work to use a browser that never stores *any* history, due to constant re-typing of passwords into frequently-used websites. Being able to define a 'expiry date' for historical data allows the user to strike their own balance between the two factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the [History Limiter chrome extension.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-limiter/dpdjaigdefdamkfcgjhbmpjbhiejjkph?hl=en-US)
This extension say that it works exactly as per your description. (even though some of the reviews on chrome store say it doesn't work properly).

As per [google forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gdqMr-YKlsw;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/authorid$3AAPn2wQc0r-xcihch1fzSpmQ7oaNUcvY50AuseKYRySbpyJP2YSUjxCNA3R358sqDmHsDIQK9QQnj%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false) what you are suggesting is not possible without an extension.

> From google forum discussion suggesting the chrome extension:
>
> > This worked. However it would be nice to set to X number of days or weeks to keep HISTORY

Answer (score 1):

Broken link above for 'History Limiter chrome extension': this appears to be most popular replacement: History Limiter Custom - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-limiter-custom/ibpfkplbhnbiklpjacjbaelahebmbmpp